# Iterate through all layer names

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d, CCTMXTileMap, is it possible to iterate through all the layers or layer names in a tilemap? I was unable to find a method for such.

Answer (score 2):

CCTMXLayer are simply children of the CCTMXTiledMap class. You can iterate over the map's children:

```
CCTMXLayer *layer;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, layer) 
{
    // do something with layer ...
}
```

If there may be other types of nodes added as children to the CCTMXTiledMap, you should filter for CCTMXLayer objects:

```
Class layerClass = [CCTMXLayer class];
CCTMXLayer *layer;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, layer) 
{
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:layerClass])
    {
        // do something with layer …
    }
}
```